# How to get current index on click angular2

Tags: angular

With angular2 is it possible to get the current `*ngFor` index value on click?
I have a list of clients and I want to get their index value.

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let customer of customers" (click)="showRadio()">
    {{ customer.customer_name }}
</button>
```

```
  showRadio(currentIndex) {
  //................    

  for(var j=0; j<myResult[currentIndex].bookingIds.length; j++) {
    alert.addInput({
      type: 'radio',
      label: myResult[currentIndex].bookingIds[j],
      value: myResult[currentIndex].bookingIds[j],
      checked: false
    });

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ngFor specify

`index` will be set to the current loop iteration for each template context.

so you need to do:

```
 <button ion-item *ngFor="let customer of customers; let i = index;" (click)="showRadio()">
          {{ i }} - {{ customer.customer_name }}
 </button>
```

Answer (score 10):

I have figure out the solution. Just let the `let i = index` and set the i as a parameter inside the function.

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let customer of customers; let i = index" (click)="showRadio(i)">
```

Credit: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zW1zHqsdyc&t=1062s)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the index in the customer object and then pass it in the function

```
[{"customer_index":1,"customer_name":"jason"},
 {"customer_index":2,"customer_name":"mary"}];
```

and then pass it in the function

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let customer of customers" (click)="showRadio(customer.customer_index)">
            {{ customer.customer_name }}
    </button>
```