# How to get the id of an item in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have called an array of item from my database using PHP as my backend language and I have displayed it correctly in my view in ionic but I tried logging the id of each of the item so I can use it to perform other task but it keeps giving me the id of the first item in the loop

the code below is the ts code in ionic to fetch data on page init

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.username = this.navParams.get('mobile');
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let data = {
    userid: this.username
  };
  this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myitems', JSON.stringify(data), requestOptions)
  //.timeout(40000)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.items =res.My_data.phone;
    console.log(this.items);
  });
}
```

below is the code when the item clicked

```
Detail(item) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

this is the html code in the view of ionic

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" on-click="Detail()">
  {{item.phone_name}} | {{item.model}} <br> {{item.serial_no}}
</ion-item>
```

each time I click it is supposed the id of the items looped like 9,10,11,12 but its returns only 9

PHP CODE BELOW(Built with laravel

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $car=caritem::where('ownerid', $request->userid)->get();
    $comp=Computer::where('ownerid', $request->userid)->get();
    $phone = useritem::where('ownerid', $request->userid)->get();
    $my_data = ['status' => 200, 'Author\'s Name' => "Ademola Segun", 'Api Version' => "v1.0",
        'Purpose' => "Findit App API", 'car' => $car, 'comp'=>$comp, 'phone'=> $phone];
    return response()->json(['My_data'=>$my_data]);

}
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: `Detail()` isnt passing anything ?

Comment: kindly check, i have update the question to include the php code but it works fine to fetch the items

Comment: details is just to log the id of the item on click of the ithe after it has been displayed in the ionic html page

Comment: @user7310495 in your code you are not passing anything to Detail function but in your ionic controller you are using Detail with parameter ??

Comment: i dont understand but your help will really be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current index on click angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459344/how-to-get-current-index-on-click-angular2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, your Detail () function is waiting for a parameter and from your html you do not give it,

Update your html like this:

`<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" on-click="Detail(item)"> .... </ion-item>`

in your ts you should got an object with id

Comment: Thanks, this Solved my trouble